# Delete multiple values inside a table from a CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table set up like this:

```
pcode       barcode   
TWOB006OL   05123456
S099R36     01234567
S086R24     05215678

Columns:
pcode varchar(255) 
barcode varchar(255)
```

and I have a CSV file that is like this:

```
barcode   
05123456,
01234567,
05215678,
```

I need to use this CSV file to remove all values inside the table

Database should end up looking like this:

```
pcode       barcode   
TWOB006OL   null
S099R36     null
S086R24     null
```

Comment: Delete the rows, or update the matched values to NULL? Either way, easiest to load the file to a tem table, then do a join in the DELETE / UPDATE statement

Comment: How would I write a query to delete just the value not the whole row?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is the question about how to load a CSV file into a table?  Or is the question about setting values in a table based on matches to another table?

Answer (score 1):

Load the CSV file into a table, say using `load data infile`.

Then:

```
update table1 t join
       csv
       on t.barcode = csv.barcode
    set t.barcode = NULL;
```